# Meaning of "With Ismail's storm to soften it the more" in Byron's "Don Juan"

Tags: poetry, meaning, lord-byron, don-juan

[Canto 8, stanza 68](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Juan_(Byron)/Canto_the_Eighth#LXVIII), from Byron's *[Don Juan](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Juan_(Byron))*:

> So much for Nature: -- by way of variety,
>   Now back to thy great joys, Civilisation!
>   And the sweet consequence of large society,
>   War, pestilence, the despot's desolation,
>   The kingly scourge, the lust of notoriety,
>   The millions slain by soldiers for their ration,
>   The scenes like Catherine's boudoir at threescore,
>   With Ismail's storm to soften it the more.

What is the meaning of **it** in the final line of the stanza? The boudoir? What does it mean then, "to soften the boudoir"?

Answer (score 3):

‘Catherine’ is empress [Catherine II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_the_Great) ‘the Great’ of Russia, and in the poem she has taken Don Juan as her lover and protégé, as she did [Grigory Potemkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigory_Potemkin), [Grigory Orlov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigory_Orlov), and others in reality.

‘It’ refers to the boudoir, but by [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) ‘boudoir’ refers to Catherine herself. This is clear from ‘at threescore’: the empress was 61 years old in 1790. So Byron is using ‘soften’ with this meaning (sense 6 in the *OED*):

> To make (a person) more sympathetic, gentle, lenient, or emotional.

‘Ismail’s storm’ refers to the the [capture of the fortified city of Izmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Izmail) from the Ottoman Empire. This city, on the lower reaches of the Danube, was besieged early in 1790 by Russian forces commanded by [Alexander Suvorov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Suvorov), and stormed on 22 December. The victory and the southern extension of her empire must have pleased Catherine, and made her better disposed to reward her favourites.